# PWA- Sample Data not installed getting error in magento2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to install sample data in PWA studio.

But getting error

> [RuntimeException]
>     Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'git@github.com:PMET-public/module-catalog-sample-data-venia.git'

I have manually downloaded

- module-catalog-sample-data-venia
- module-configurable-sample-data-venia
- module-customer-sample-data-venia
- module-sales-sample-data-venia
- module-tax-sample-data-venia
- sample-data-media-venia

But where to where to add it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the same error so i have downloaded all modules manually and then i put all downloaded modules in `app/code/Magento` directory except **sample-data-media-venia**. for **sample-data-media-venia** Copy catalog folder from it and paste it into `pub/media/`

```
/var/www/html/M231/app/code/Magento/CatalogSampleDataVenia
/var/www/html/M231/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableSampleDataVenia
/var/www/html/M231/app/code/Magento/CustomerSampleDataVenia
/var/www/html/M231/app/code/Magento/SalesSampleDataVenia
/var/www/html/M231/app/code/Magento/TaxSampleDataVenia
```

then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it helped to run

```
composer update
```

then the shell asked me to go to github to generate an oAuth token. I generated it, pasted it to the shell and it finished successfully.

Afterwards I ran

```
bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh
```

again and it finished successfully.

Please be mindful that `composer update` will update all your dependencies to newest versions, therefore it should only be used in a development environment as using it in production can break your site.

Answer (score 2):

in the root folder of Magento rename `auth.json.sample` to `auth.json`

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "--------------",
            "password": "--------------"
        }
    },
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "-------------"
    }
}
```

for username and password

go to https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/account/
create access  key by clicking on market place tab->create a new access key, copy and paste the public and private key

in Github auth
go to https://github.com/settings/tokens
(**click on profile pic -> setting -> Developer settings -> personal acces token -> generate new token**)
and generate new token and paste it

now you can run `bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh`
and install